# Updating path to include Android tools directory?

Tags: windows, android

Total noob here. Just installed eclipse and SDK. I was instructed to

"To update your PATH variable to include the Android tools directory, right-click
Computer and choose Properties. In Vista, you also need to click Advanced System
Settings. You continue by clicking the Advanced tab of the System Properties dialog
and clicking the Environment Variables button.
In the System Variables section, edit the PATH variable and add the path to the tools
directory."

Can someone please explain how I edit the PATH variable? Do I click "New" and point to the SDK tools folder?

Comment: try clicking edit, and add it by separating with ;

Comment: Thanks a lot! Figured it out myself. Sorry for being such a noob ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you just add a semicolon ; and add the tools path. ;)